# Central Bank Meeting Date Curve in QuantLib

Tags: quantlib

Is it possible to construct a central bank meeting date curve, using futures prices & OIS rates, in QuantLib?
Specifically, I mean a yield curve with flat (constant) forward rates in between meeting dates, and discontinuous moves on meeting dates (or 1 day after I guess, given that typically the rate change applies the next day).
If so, how?

Comment: Do you need to distinguish the [effective fed funds rate](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/FEDFUNDS), which the futures reference, from the [target rate](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DFEDTARU), which usually stays constant between [FOMC meetings](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm) (but on rare occasions can change between meetings)?

Comment: Very good question. I want to model the target rate, rather than the effective fed funds rate.

Comment: I made a typo in my original question so just corrected "spot rates" -> "forward rates". i.e. the YC is composed of many forward rates with 1 day expiry representing the overnight cash target rate.

Answer (score 0):

From my first line of thought:

1. Obtain OIS 1D,1M,2M,...12M
2. Use the Fed Funds Target - EFFR spread and apply that spread to each OIS curve.
3. Convert the simple 1,2, 3M OIS swaps to 1M, 1M1M, 2M2M forward rate curves. This is a simple process is easily bootstrapped.
4. Interpolate (Linear, spline etc.) between each data point.

   - In your example- you request the jumps to be after specific "meeting dates". You could iterate through each data point, and if OIS_next - OIS_t > 25bps. You could simply apply a function that increases it after the meeting date (Which is between dates next and t) based on this condition (Assuming no "micro" hikes or ECB style hikes)